# Spark executors fails on Kubernetes (EKS) --podName is missing

Tags: java, apache-spark, kubernetes, pyspark

I am running Spark 3.3.1 in cluster mode in Kubernetes using Java.

Spark conf:

```java
    public SparkConf sparkConf() {
        return new SparkConf()
                .set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "600")
                .set("spark.rdd.compress", "true")
                .set("spark.ui.prometheus.enabled","true")
                .set("spark.executor.processTreeMetrics.enabled","true")
                .set("*.sink.prometheusServlet.class","org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.PrometheusServlet")
                .set("*.sink.prometheusServlet.path","/metrics/prometheus")
                .set("spark.submit.deployMode","cluster")
                .set("spark.kubernetes.container.image","45454454.dkr.ecr.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/dev/feature-gen:v3.3.1")
                .set("spark.kubernetes.container.image.pullPolicy","Always")
                .set("spark.kubernetes.namespace","default")
                .set("spark.kubernetes.executor.podNamePrefix","spark-executor")
                .set("spark.kubernetes.authenticate.executor.serviceAccountName","spark")
                .set("spark.kubernetes.dynamicAllocation.deleteGracePeriod","20")
                .set("spark.shuffle.service.enabled","true")
                .set("spark.kubernetes.executor.request.cores", "4")
                .set("spark.kubernetes.executor.limit.cores", "4")
                .set("spark.executor.memory", "4g")
                .set("spark.executor.instances", "1")
                .set("spark.ui.port", "4040")
                .setAppName(appName)
                .setMaster("k8s://https://XXXXXXXX.yl3.eu-north-1.eks.amazonaws.com:443");
    }
```

Executor pod being created but after couple of seconds I got following logs and pod being recreated.

```
│ + SPARK_CLASSPATH='/opt/spark/conf::/opt/spark/jars/*'                                                                                                                                                                                                  │
│ + case "$1" in                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          │
│ + shift 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               │
│ + CMD=(${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java "${SPARK_EXECUTOR_JAVA_OPTS[@]}" -Xms$SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY -Xmx$SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY -cp "$SPARK_CLASSPATH:$SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH" org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.KubernetesExecutorBackend --driver-url $SPARK_D │
│ + exec /usr/bin/tini -s -- /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNA │
│ Unrecognized options: --podName                                                                                                                                                                                                                         │
│                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         │
│ Usage: org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.KubernetesExecutorBackend [options]                                                                                                                                                                       │
│                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         │
│  Options are:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           │
│    --driver-url <driverUrl>                                                                                                                                                                                                                             │
│    --executor-id <executorId>                                                                                                                                                                                                                           │
│    --bind-address <bindAddress>                                                                                                                                                                                                                         │
│    --hostname <hostname>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                │
│    --cores <cores>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      │
│    --resourcesFile <fileWithJSONResourceInformation>                                                                                                                                                                                                    │
│    --app-id <appid>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     │
│    --worker-url <workerUrl>                                                                                                                                                                                                                             │
│    --resourceProfileId <id>                                                                                                                                                                                                                             │
│    --podName <podName>
stream closed
```

I can not understand why pod's name unrecognized? What am I doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: Seems like you did not print the full width of the logs in that second code block (the one saying Unrecognized options `--podName`. Could you add that?

Comment: Line 6 contains "Unrecognized options --podName" and nothing else.

Comment: What about lines 4 and 5?

Comment: I got the same behavior, this feels like a bug on Spark's side, there is no good reason why the SPARK_EXECUTOR_POD_NAME should be missing

Answer (score 0):

After troubleshooting I got it working using following setup:

I have created podtemplate.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
spec:
  containers:
    - args:
      env:
        - name: SPARK_EXECUTOR_POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
```

then configured spark to use it:

```
           .set("spark.kubernetes.executor.podTemplateFile","/podtemplate.yaml")
```

But still do not understand why I did not get it automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I've met this error and the problem was that the spark image of the driver was different from the executors' spark image. Try check on those